# Cloudfront setup for main domain without using route53

Tags: dns, amazon-cloudfront, cname, a-records

We are planning to use cloudfront distribution for our main domain and the setup will be as follows.

Cloudfront Origin - route.domain.com -> Remote Server IP address(xx.xx.xx.xx)
www.domain.com, domain.com ->  d123.cloudfront.com

As we know, we can setup CNAME for www.domain.com to point to cloudfront distribution(d123.cloudfront.net). However, for domain.com we should point A record to IP address and its not possible to setup CNAME record.

In route53, there is an option called **Alias** which can be used to point the domain to Cloudfront. But, our domain.com nameserver uses different provider and we would like to stick with current nameserver.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a limitation in DNS itself, there is no way to accomplish this without a DNS hosting provider that supports an alias-like feature, sometimes called an "ANAME" or "flattened CNAME".  Route 53 is of course the canonical example.  CloudFlare and DNS Made Easy are others.

Or use a [service like this one](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect)¹ to redirect your naked domain name to the www address, which would be your "real" site.  They give you a single IP address for your A record.  Note that your current DNS provider may have a "redirection" option that does this.  It is not properly a part of DNS, but some providers allow you to configure domain redirections in their DNS portal.

Or migrate your DNS *hosting* to Route 53, keeping your DNS *registration* with your current vendor.  In my mind, there is really no compelling reason not to use Route 53.  See [Making Route 53 the DNS Service for a Domain That's in Use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) for migrating to Route 53 without disruption, noting that the final step -- *Transfer Domain Registration to Amazon Route 53* -- is entirely optional, as mentioned in the docs.

---

¹ *this one* is not a service I am affiliated with or have ever used in production, because I built my own service for that purpose using EC2, which is another option but outside the scope of this answer.  This is intended as an example, not an endorsement.

Comment: A reason not to use Route53 is not to pay the Route53 hosting zone fee